# WPF C# Caching Results to Text then to Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caching, listbox

I'm playing around with this. I will implement some type of caching on objects in the application, but I want to get a full understanding of how it works. All data displayed is fake and test data. No PHI is used.

The Goal: Cache SQL table results to text file on local machine.

What works?
Text File created from SQL table. 
Reading the Text File in the app.

What doesn't work?
Displaying the data in the Listbox or Combobox.

What's happening?
The text file is neat and clean. 1 record per row. No extra spaces. When I read the text file into a MessageBox, bingo. Nice, neat, easy to read. When I display the text into a ComboBox or ListBox, each letter in every full name is a new row. [image]

The XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Name of Patient - " HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBox Name="FullName" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
             Text="{Binding Path=EmployeeName, Mode=TwoWay}"
             Height="30" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Button Name="Search" Content="Search" Click="Search_Click"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Height="30" Width="150" />
    <ListBox Height="200" Width="200" Name="LbFullName"
             ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
</Grid>
```

The C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    //cache object
    private readonly ObjectCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string dbFile = path + @"\\Razor Sharp Technology\\PharmaSYS Management Suite\\Files\\PatientNames.txt";
        SendSqlToText(dbFile);
    }

    private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ReSharper disable once RedundantAssignment
        if (!(_cache["cachecontents"] is string cacheContents))
        {
            var policy = new CacheItemPolicy {AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(10.0)};

            var filePaths = new List<string>();
            var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            filePaths.Add(path + "\\Razor Sharp Technology\\PharmaSYS Management Suite\\Files\\PatientNames.txt");

            policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(new
                                          HostFileChangeMonitor(filePaths));

            cacheContents =
                File.ReadAllText(path + "\\Razor Sharp Technology\\PharmaSYS Management Suite\\Files\\PatientNames.txt");

            _cache.Set("cachecontents", cacheContents, policy);
            LbFullName.DataContext = cacheContents;
            MessageBox.Show(cacheContents);
        }
    }

    private void SendSqlToText(string dbFile)
    {
        var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconn"].ConnectionString;
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            var cmd = "SELECT FullName FROM[dbo].[PatientData]";
            var command = new SqlCommand(cmd, sqlConnection);
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(dbFile, false))
            {
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    file.WriteLine(sqlReader["FullName"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` sets the ItemsSource to the string in `LbFullName.DataContext` (i.e. `cacheContents`). ItemsSource expects an IEnumerable, string is `IEnumerable<char>`, hence you see single characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [File.ReadAllLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsy4fhsa(v=vs.110).aspx). That way you get each line as a string in a string[] which you can bind on.

### Step1

```
var strings = File.ReadAllLines(path + "\\Razor Sharp Technology\\PharmaSYS Management Suite\\Files\\PatientNames.txt");
```

### Step2

Bind the ItemSource of the ComboBox to the string[] you filled with lines in Step1.

Using `ItemSource="{Binding}"`

Comment: If i could help fix your problem, i'd happy if you accept the answer :)